# Characterization of the adjoint of a $C_0$-Semigoup infinitesimal generator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

I am looking for characterizations of the adjoint operator of the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigoup in Hilbert spaces. All I could find in the literature is that if $(A, D(A))$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$ semigroup $S(t)$ in $X$ where $X$ is a reflexive Banach space then $(A^*, D(A^*))$ the adjoint of $(A, D(A))$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $S^*(t)$ which is the adjoint of $S(t)$, hence the characterizations are provided by Hille-Yosida and Lumer-Phillips theorems.

Are there any other characterizations of the generator $(A, D(A))$ or especially its adjoint $(A^*, D(A^*))$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by characterization?

Comment: @S.Maths Necessary and/or sufficient conditions on the operator $(A, D(A))$ to be a generator of a semigroup or a strongly continuous semigroup on a Hilbert space.

Comment: You mean others than Hille-Yosida and Lumer-Phillips?

Comment: @S.Maths  Yes, sorry for the delay.